# netns: execute command from default namespace from another namespace

Tags: linux, linux-namespaces

I ssh into a linux machine using nets namespace (command below)

```
ip netns exec NAME_SPACE ssh root@192.168.2.100
```

From there I want to execute some command(say "ifconfig") in default name space from this.

Comment: In which default namespace do you want to run your command : the originating host from which you launched "ip netns ..." or on the remote machine on which you are connected with "ssh" ?

Comment: on default namespace of the remote machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that a process is running in the default network namespace (typically process number 1), you can use tools like [nsenter](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) to run a command in the same network namespace (`-n` option):

```
# nsenter -t 1 -n ifconfig
```